# PlaceHolder reason for Download Failure using Download Manager in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using Download Manager to download files of types(.mov, .pdf, .png). When I call download manager, download fails giving reason as Place holder. What does place holder mean and how do I fix this issue? Please help!

My code is as follows:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrlFile))
    .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,
        (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), downloadFileName).setNotificationVisibility(visibility);

mEnqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
mDownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD_STATUS"+intent.getAction());
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(mEnqueue);
            Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                Log.d("getColumnIndex()", "Reason: " + c
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)+DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL");
                } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    Log.d("handleData()", "Reason: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)));
                    Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD_STATUS_FAILED");
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the column "COLUMN_REASON" is an int and not a String (despite some examples I have seen that imply it is a string).

Hence you should be using:

```
Log.d("handleData()", "Reason: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)));
```

The value can be found:
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_REASON)
and
[here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1)